# How to get the id of a link when pressed in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm using Xcode 5, and need to get the dom id of a link when you click on it (not before).

Comment: `[link getIDWhenBeingClickedButNotBefore]`

Comment: What do you mean by the ID? As part of the query string, or the DOM ID?